# custom endpoint in wp plugin

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, endpoint, wordpress-plugin-creation

How do achieve the custom endpoint in wodpress plugin like

> http://example.com/classroom/group/%7Bgroup_id%7D

I want to have the /classroom/ at root level after domain name which will load classroom-template of plugin and group-template for the group.

So here need two templates to load with custom url.

http://example.com/classroom/ which will load classroom-template and
http://example.com/classroom/group/1 which will load group-template.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late but here is what I did in a similar scenario. It could be done differently or better optimized. This served my purpose.

Here I am adding an endpoint like WooCommerce as a thank you page which is a virtual page, not listed in the pages list in WP dashboard.

```
add_action('init', function () {
    add_rewrite_endpoint('order-received', EP_PERMALINK | EP_PAGES);
});
```

Here I am letting WP know that this query var will be necessary later. I might use that later.

```
add_filter('query_vars', function ($vars) {
    $vars[] = 'order-received';
    return $vars;
});
```

Here, adding the custom endpoint in the rewrite rules so that WP will load the data I want it to load on this URL.

```
add_filter('generate_rewrite_rules', function ($wp_rewrite) {
    $new_rules = array('order/order-received/' => 'index.php?order-received=1');
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
    return $wp_rewrite;
});
```

Here I am just making a shortcode for orders page.

```
add_shortcode('orders-page', array($this, 'tm_generate_shortcode_for_orders_page'));

function tm_generate_shortcode_for_orders_page() {
    global $wp;
    $is_thankyou_page = isset($wp->query_vars['order-received']);

    if($is_thankyou_page) {
        // thank you content goes here
    } else {
        // Orders page content goes here
    }
}
```

And here I am adding that shortcode into a custom page which will automatically get created if placed on a plugin activation hook.

```
function create_orders_page()
{
    $title = 'Order';
    $slug = 'order';

    // Check if the page already exists
    $page = get_page_by_path($slug);
    if (!$page) {
        // Create the page if it does not exist
        $page_id = wp_insert_post(array(
            'post_title'   => $title,
            'post_name'    => $slug,
            'post_content' => '[orders-page]',
            'post_status'  => 'publish',
            'post_type'    => 'page'
        ));
    }
}
```

I can redirect to thank you page like so, from any other page, with custom data.

```
$thank_you_url = '';
$thank_you_url = add_query_arg(array('order_id' => $order_id), '/order-translation-step-three/order-received');
wp_redirect($thank_you_url);
```

Answer (score 0):

First make a page titled "classroom". This becomes your /classroom route. Then create another page titled "group". Make the classroom page as the parent of this page. As a result this page slug becomes /classroom/group. Now all the /classroom/group/id requests come to your group page. In this page, your plugin needs to get the URL (like using $wp->request, [see](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/274569/how-to-get-url-of-current-page-displayed)) and extract the id part of it. Based on that id load your template.

Comment: I wanted to have with plugin only and don't wanted to create any page from the dashboard.

Comment: Your plugin can create all these pages programmatically upon activation (and of course check if they were not created before by previous installation). You can use standard commands like wp_insert_post to create pages programmatically and insert your plugin shorcodes in them for further customization. This is a standard wp process

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom post type for classroom and assign a template to it by using its file name like this

```
single-classroomcustomposttype.php
```

Codex details here for [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#Single_Post_display)

To make a hierarchical custom post type, you have to have the `page-attributes` set in the `supports` array and the `hierarchical` flag set to `true`.

To load a different template for Groups I think the easiest solution is to use this if statement inside `single-classroomcustomposttype.php`

```
if( $post->post_parent != 0 ) {
    // not top level
} else {
    // top level page
}
```

Comment: I don't wont to create custom post type